# How to install a .exe in the app service of Microsoft Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I published a web application in a app service of Microsoft Azure, but my application needs a driver to connect with a IBM database, that driver is installed in the machine where I developed the application but now I need to install the ".exe" file that contains that driver in the app service of Microsoft Azure in order to get my application running correctly.

How can I install a .exe file in app service of Microsoft Azure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't install 3rd party software in App Service.  You should look at deploying your app in a Virtual Machine instead.  You'll be able to remote desktop to it and install your database driver.

Answer (score 0):

Azure App Service **doesn't allow** installing any software to it.

You can include some executable (and its files) in your code tree, but writing to the filesystem or registry is denied.

Comment: Abyway it's perfectly feasible `manually` install (write) files to the temporary directory obtained with `Path.GetTempPath()`

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that you can't.

If the executable does not require complex dependencies you can store it in the assembly resources and write into a temp directory (check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52013428/is-is-possible-to-browse-an-azure-app-service-temp-directory)).

Another option is to have it deployed directly with your project tree.

Than you can invoke it with `System.Diagnostics` APIs.

But be aware if you're running a **Linux** App Service you need to set the file to executable.
I suggest to invoke directy the shell command: `/bin/chmod +x your_cmd`.